# How to create middle folders on an already existing path?

Tags: java, groovy

I have a path like this:

```
/foo/bar/... (can contain other subdirs or files)
```

I want to add a "middle" folder in the mid of said path, leading to:

```
/foo/middle/bar/...
```

What's an elegant way to do that?

Comment: You want to create a folder?  Or just add `/middle` to the middle of a string?  Which bit are you struggling with?  Also, Java AND Groovy?  Or just Java?  Or just Groovy?

Comment: And when you say "_mid of said path_", but "_(can contain other subdirs or files)_", where do you expect `/middle` to appear in (for example) `a/b/c/d/e`

Comment: between foo and bar, it's bar that could contain subdirs

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so what you can do is have a path like the following that represents the absolute path of foo/bar/

```java
Path path = Paths.get("foo", "bar");
```

Then you can get the parent of the current path.

```java
Path parent = path.getParent();
```

Then you can resolve a sibling, a new path.

```java
Path newChild = parent.resolve("middle");
```

Then you cna create that path if it doesnt exist.

```java
Files.createDirectory(newChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have, or what you want, but assuming your path is a String

```
def path = "/foo/bar/baz/whee/yay"
```

You could just split the string on `/`

```
def segments = path.split('/')
```

insert one at position 2 (split has left us an empty entry before the initial `/`)

```
def inserted = segments[0..1] + 'new' + segments[2..-1]
```

Then join them back together

```
assert inserted.join('/') == '/foo/new/bar/baz/whee/yay'
```